# iOS CoreBluetooth indicate characteristic read receipt

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

Per [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcharacteristicproperties/1519085-indicate), the Core Bluetooth Characteristic of type `indicate` is:

> A property that indicates the peripheral permits notifications of the characteristic’s value, with a response from the central to indicate receipt of the notification.

How does the central perform the receipt of the notification?  Is this handled internally by Core Bluetooth, or is there an API for this? Or is it expected that the Bluetooth device provide a way to do this, such as through a write characteristic?

Comment: It is handled internally by the Bluetooth stack on iOS.

Comment: Paulw11 is correct, unfortunately. With Indications the packet is ack'ed internally by Apple's BT stack at the Host Layer. Imo the main issue with this is that you still have no guarantee that the packet has arrived at application layer (your app). The fact is that all ble packets are ack'ed at Link Layer regardless. So I would say that on iOS indications give you little benefit over notifications since you would have to implement your own ack at app level anyways. Indications are useful however for flow control if you intend to send a lot of data (stream) that risk being lost at link layer.